# Are Message Queue Triggers betters than Http Triggers for scalability?

Tags: azure, architecture, message-queue, azure-functions, serverless-architecture

2 types of triggers for Azure Functions are message queues and http triggers. I'm guessing that one difference is that with http triggers a request could be denied if there are not enough instances to service the request, whereas with message queues it will check if there is an instance available and if not spin one up before trying to process the message. Is that a correct understanding?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite..! I think you're getting the information from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#avoid-long-running-functions):

> Whenever possible, refactor large functions into smaller function sets that work together and return responses fast. For example, a webhook or HTTP trigger function might require an acknowledgment response within a certain time limit; it is common for webhooks to require an immediate response.

The acknowledgement within a certain time limit is all about how long the client is willing to wait for a response. So if you were to execute some task that takes a long time (on the order of minutes), you may not receive an informative response because the client would just call the connection dead. However, your function would still execute just fine as long as it stayed within the [functionTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan) limits (one a consumption plan, the default is 5 minutes, max being 10 minutes).